# How do I separate my code into their own separate classes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class, console-application

How do I separate my code into their own classes and still have it function the same? This is currently what my code looks like.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using XCENT.JobServer.JobPlugIn;
using System.IO;
using HPD.API.Utility.DataAccess;

namespace DataPurge
{
    public class Purge : IJob, IJobControl {

        public IJobControl JobControl { get { return ( this ); } }
        public int MaxInstanceCount { get { return 1; } }
        public string Name { get { return "DataPurge"; } }        

        public Purge() { }

        public void Run( string XmlFragment ) {
            XmlNode xmlNode = null;

            try
            {
                xmlNode = Common.ConstructXmlNodeFromString(XmlFragment, "Params");
                var list = DataList();

                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    var factory = new PurgerFactory(item);
                    IPurger purge = factory.Purger;

                    purge.Purge();

                    purge = null;
                    factory = null;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public interface IPurger
        {
            void Purge();
        }

        public enum PurgeType
        {
            File,
            Database,
        }

        public class FilePurger : IPurger
        {
            private Parameters parameter;
            public FilePurger(Parameters parameter)
            {
                this.parameter = parameter;
            }

            public void Purge()
            {
                var files = new DirectoryInfo(parameter.FilePath).GetFiles();
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (DateTime.Now - file.CreationTime > TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
                    {
                        File.Delete(file.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public class DbPurger : IPurger
        {
            private Parameters parameter;
            public DbPurger(Parameters parameter)
            {
                this.parameter = parameter;
            }

            public void Purge()
            {
                var access = new SqlDataAccess();
                var sqlParams = new Dictionary<string, object>();

                sqlParams.Add("@OlderThanDays", parameter.OlderThanDays);

                access.ExecuteNonQuery(parameter.CString, parameter.SPName, sqlParams, 30, false);               
            }
        }

        private List<Parameters> DataList()
        {
            var sqlParams = new SqlDataAccess();

            var list = sqlParams.GetDataTableAsList<Parameters>("Data Source = MYSERVER; Initial Catalog = MYDATABASE; User ID = UID; Password = PASSWORD;", "purge.spoDataTable", null);

            return list;
        }

        public class PurgerFactory
        {
            public IPurger Purger { get; set; }

            public PurgerFactory(Parameters parameter)
            {
                PurgeType type = (PurgeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PurgeType), parameter.PurgeType);

                switch (type)
                {
                    case PurgeType.File:
                        Purger = new FilePurger(parameter);
                        break;
                    case PurgeType.Database:
                        Purger = new DbPurger(parameter);
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw new NotImplementedException();
                }
            }            
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Used to submit a job via the job monitor
        /// </summary>
        public XmlNode JobXMLNode => Common.ConstructXmlNodeFromString("" +
                    "<JobParams>" +
                    "   <Param Name=\"InfrastructureAPI\" DataType=\"String\">" +
                    "       <Description>Infrastructure API URL.</Description>" +
                    "   </Param>" +
                    "   <Param Name=\"EnvironmentName\" DataType=\"String\">" +
                    "       <Description>The current environment.</Description>" +
                    "   </Param>" +
                    "</JobParams>",
                    "JobParams");

    }
}
```

Currently all parts of the program are stuffed into this one single class. I want to separate them out into their own separate classes to make the code much cleaner but still have it function the same. I'm still a beginner coder and don't know the first place to start. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You already have different `public class`es. You will need to reference them, individually if you're wanting to use them in other classes.

Comment: Just put your classes, enums and interfaces into separate files next to Purge.cs. I recommend naming the same as the containing class e.g. The FilePurger class in the file FilePurger.cs.

Answer (score 2):

You should create a file `IPurger.cs` for the interface `IPurger`, then a file `FilePurger.cs` for the class `FilePurger`, the file `DbPurger.cs` for the class `DbPurger` and lastly `PurgerFactory.cs` for the class `PurgerFactory`.

That should clean up your code quite well.

If that enum is used from multiple places, you may want to place it in its own class too, perhaps a generic `Enums.cs`.

Comment: What about the IPurger? It has 4 references in the code. Enum has 5 references. Should I move them both together to a separate class?

Comment: If you get "The type or namespace name 'blabla' could not be found", right click on the word underined in red, clilck "quick actions and factoring" and in the context menu you get suggested adding a "using [namespace];". Click on that and you're good to go.